# Python: 'IndexError: list assignment index out of range' from 2d-List

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, arraylist, index-error

I got the error

```
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

by using the following code:

```
expC = 0
imgC = 0
pictures = [[x for x in range(7)] for y in range(25)]
for i in experimentNames:
    for pictureData in glob.iglob('{}/**/*.png'.format(i), recursive=True):
        img = cv.imread(pictureData)
        pictures[expC][imgC] = img
        imgC = imgC + 1
    expC = expC + 1
```

The goal of this code is to write pictures in a 2 dimensional list. Each column should represent one experiment. There are seven experiments with 25 pictures. They should be saved in the matching column.

I tried the code above and changed the indexes and the declaration of the matrix. Still didn't work.

Comment: You are not resetting `imgC` at the end of the `for pictureData` loop, so it goes beyond 7. also, note that the dimensions of your 2d array are `(25,7), so you will also need to reverse expC and imgC in `pictures[expC][imgC] = img`

Comment: @FlorentMonin Good points. I changed that, but I got the same error again.

Comment: Can you update your question to reflect those changes then? :) Two things: are you sure you have no more than 25 images per experiment? And also, you don't need to initialise your list, you could simply append to it at every iteration, then you wouldn't have to worry about how many pictures there are

Comment: The problem was (next to the others) that i had more than 25 images :/ Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error.
I have more than 25 images so the range of the list is too small. Moreover I forgot resetting imgC.